# How to design services in 2 different java-spring projects

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have two different projects. One is a big spring mvc web application. And another is simple web service based on the spring too. Both projects have in dependencies third project that contains entities and dao layer classes.
And now I need some logic from the first project (web app) to use in the second one (ws).
So I transferred service and some of business logic from the first project to third. I didn't transferred DTO classes and some specific spring things like classes that work with spring security. Therefore my business classes multiples. Now I have about 20 classes in third project (like "UserService") and 15 classes (like "UserDtoService") in first project. It's rather hard to control all this stuff and find functions that I need. What should I do in this situation? Is it time to combine projects in one? Or just return service classes back and duplicate code in project two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done things fine , no need to copy stuff back to the Spring Web Application. Only thing is you need to understand the role of each object/service in the application. From my point of view, Service consumers  just need to remap the response back from the Service in such way that this component understand, in which case really not  a "UserDtoService", it can be mapper or adapter, it should not have the same logic "UserService".